# Access returned FindOne Mongoose Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Unable to access returned Mongoose/Mongo data with the following code:

```
Site.findOne({_id:id}).exec(function ( err, site ){ 
    console.log(site) // This will log all site data
    console.log(site.name) // This states - Cannot read Property 'name' of null 
})
```

Why is't it allowing me to access the .name of site? I works if i remove the _id parameter and use site[0].name . Im sure it must be something im overlooking. Just a side note that site.name is populated within Mongo.

Site Schema:

```
var SiteSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    content:String
});

var Site = mongoose.model('Site',SiteSchema, 'site')
```

**_id** is set by Mongo when created.

Comment: And, you should always check for `err`: if it is set, `site` will not contain anything useful...

Comment: @MarcoS url was a typo, I've corrected that. I check for err's and there are none, the site data is set. I just cannot access the specific items.

Answer (score 0):

A good explanation for Mongoose `findOne()` to return a successful response and a null result, is that the query does not match to any document... :-)
Are you sure the `id` you pass is present in the collection?

Comment: The id is present within the collection, im able to console.log the full data set for the stated id. Only when i drill down into an item in the returned array will it prompt with "TypeError:cannor read property 'name' of null"

Comment: `findOne()` is not returning an `array`, but `null`... Are you completely sure the **variable** `id` contains the _id of a document in the collection?

Comment: Are you sayng that "console.log(site) // This will log all site data" and then "console.log(site.name) // This states - Cannot read Property 'name' of null" ??? Can you show the output of `console.log(site)` ? It looks really strange, to me...